# Precedence of operators in BNF grammar

Tags: syntax, bnf, operator-precedence

I'm doing a homework assignment where I am give some BNF grammar:

```
<assign> -> <id> = <expr>
<id> -> A | B | C
<expr> -> <expr> + <term>
      | <term>
<term> -> <term> * <factor>
      | <factor>
<factor> -> ( <expr> )
      | <id>
```

and the question is:

"Rewrite this grammar so that the `+` operator is right associative and takes precedence over the `*` operator."

A classmate suggested we simply switch the `+` and `*` operators and then `+` will have precedence and gain right association, however I don't think this is correct since the question is recursive.

My question is, does the `+` operator gain precedence and right association by simply switching it with the `*` operator? My two thoughts are to remove the recursion and do what my classmate suggests, or put the `+` operator in a condition where is must be surrounded by `(` and `)` to work.

Maybe I'm over thinking this?

Comment: swapping `+` and `*` in the grammar will clearly swap the precedence, but making them right-associative is a seperate step

Comment: @MooningDuck Let me just take a picture of that so I can say I told you so to my friend... Ok done. 

So now referring to right-association would I simply be able to make the addition operator recursively in parenthesis and cut out the multiplication at that point? I believe that would be consider right association. Ex. `A = B * (C + (C + (C + C)))`

Comment: Associativity is (it seems to me) related to the kind of recursion. As you can see in your example, both expr and term are left-recursive and have left-associativity. Maybe changing the type of recursion used in the production you are interested changes it's associativity also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swapping + and * in the grammar will clearly swap the precedence, but making them right-associative is a separate step, so that's easy.

However, for Right-vs-Left associativity, I'm having trouble understanding your suggestions, but both of them seem wrong.

If we take the sample input `A = A + B + C`, then your grammar parses it like this:

```
assign: <id> = <expr>
    id: A
    expr: <expr> + <term>
        expr: <expr> + <term>
            expr: <expr> + <term>
                expr: <term>
                term: <factor>
                    factor: <id>
                         id: A
            term: <factor>
                factor: <id>
                    id: B
        term: <factor>
            factor: <id>
                id: C
```

Or, if you prefer the same thing in a parenthetical format:

```
(A) = ((((A))+(B))+(C))
```

Notice that the innermost and thus first evaluated `+` is the one farthest to the *left*.  Thus, your grammar has Left associativity.  You need to change `expr` and `term` so that the first one evaluated is the one farthest to the *right* for the grammar to have right associativity.  Parenthesis provide a way to "overrule" of whatever the associativity the grammar has, but otherwise aren't really related to the associativity.